# How to output a variable using the <h1> tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to output “Hello firstName lastName!” in the heading of the HTML using `<h1>` but I don't know how to do it. Right now I just have the variables declared but if I try to output them using `<h1>` is doesn't use the variables and just outputs as exactly "firstName lastName." Any help is appreciated! This is my code right now.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #ffccff;
}

h1 {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
<body>
</body>
<script>
var firstName = 'Ryan';
var lastName = 'Higgins';
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not enough code to help us diagnose your problem.  Please include your actual JS function and the HTML which uses it.

Comment: Please add your current HTML code by clicking the [edit] link above.

Answer (score 3):

```
var h1 = document.createElement("h1");                
var h1Text = document.createTextNode("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName +" !");         
h1.appendChild(h1Text);                              
document.body.appendChild(h1);
```